# How to install docker on Windows7 and create a Linux machine over docker

Tags: windows-7, docker

How can I install Docker on my windows 7 machine and dock a Linux distro,say Ubuntu 14.04?

What are the things to be done before installation process. Do I need to allocate a specific partition for Docker images. Someone please give a detailed idea.

Answer (score 2):

See the directions [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/#installation) on Docker's website for running Boot2Docker.

The Docker images will be stored within the installed virtual machine for you and automatically expand as necessary.

Once you have it installed, to install Ubuntu 14.04 just run the following command within Boot2Docker:

```
docker run ubuntu:14.04
```

Comment: Apparently it is only supported on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

There is another similar question in Stack Exchange. Read it at this link: [Another similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1163594/how-to-install-docker-on-windows-7-machine)

We are now in 2019. An extract from there... On Win7 you need to install Docker Toolbox:

> To run Docker natively on Windows , you need Hyper-V support which
>   isn't included in Windows 7. You can see an official workaround below
>   : If you have an earlier Windows system that doesn’t meet the Docker
>   for Windows requirements, get Docker Toolbox. The Docker Toolbox setup
>   does not run Docker natively on Windows. Instead, it uses
>   docker-machine to create and attach to a virtual machine (VM). This
>   machine is a Linux VM that hosts Docker for you on your Windows
>   system.