# How to install docker on windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, docker

My OS is supporting windows 7 and i need to install docker for my hyperledger project. Apparently, docker is available for windows 10. What should i do in this case, because upgrading my OS version is not possible as of this moment.

Answer (score 26):

**Important Note : Docker Toolbox has been deprecated and users are advised to move to Docker Desktop. A migration guide can be found here : https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/docker-toolbox/**

> To run Docker natively on Windows , you need Hyper-V support which
> isn't included in Windows 7. You can see an official workaround below
> :
>
> From `docker.com`
>
> > If you have an earlier Windows system that doesn’t meet
> > the Docker for Windows requirements, get Docker Toolbox.
> >
> > See Docker Toolbox Overview for help on installing Docker with
> > Toolbox.
> >
> > The Docker Toolbox setup does not run Docker natively on Windows.
> > Instead, it uses docker-machine to create and attach to a virtual
> > machine (VM). This machine is a Linux VM that hosts Docker for you on
> > your Windows system.
> >
> > Requirements
> >
> > To run Docker, your machine must have a 64-bit operating system
> > running Windows 7 or higher. Additionally, you must make sure that
> > virtualization is enabled on your machine. For details, see the
> > Toolbox install instructions for Windows.
>
> Installing Docker Toolbox and hosting containers from the Linux VM
> shouldn't be a problem as long as you have decent hardware available.
>
> For installation links and tutorials : [Install Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/)
>
> For Docker Toolbox : [Install Docker Toolbox on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)

Comment: @WEFX apparently there have been some changes in docker's own tutorial. you can follow https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/ for toolbox , i've also updated the answer to reflect the changes on docker pages

Comment: Is this still correct in 2018?

Comment: it is and will be unless microsoft decides to support hyper-v on windows 7

Comment: It seems that Docker Toolbox has been deprecated

Comment: I've added an edit for the new migration page